# Payment fee is not included in invoice amount

Tags: magento-1.9, payment

I have added some payment charge based on the payment mode chosen by customer.
Below is my config.xml

```
<sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <surcharge>
                        <class>ucs_surcharge/sales_quote_address_total_fee</class>
                        <after>subtotal</after>
                    </surcharge>
                </totals>
            </quote>
       </sales>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_address>
                <surcharge>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </surcharge>
                <base_surcharge>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </base_surcharge>
            </sales_convert_quote_address>
            <sales_convert_quote>
                <surcharge><to_order>*</to_order></surcharge>
            </sales_convert_quote>
        </fieldsets>
```

Below is my code,

```
<?php
class Ucs_Surcharge_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Fee extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCode('surcharge');
    }


    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        parent::collect($address);


        $this->_setAmount(0);
        $this->_setBaseAmount(0);

        $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $this; //this makes only address type shipping to come through
        }

        $session  = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $quote_id = $session->getQuoteId();

        if($quote_id){

                $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote_id );

            try{

                    $charges = 0.02;
                    $subTotal = $address->getFeeAmount()+$quote->getSubtotal();

                    $charges = 0.02*$subTotal;

        Mage::log('Calculation'.$charges, null, 'Ami.log');
                    $address->setSurcharge($charges);
                    $address->setBaseSurcharge($charges);


                    $quote->setSurcharge($charges);

                    $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() + $address->getSurcharge());
                    $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseSurcharge());
                } 
        }


    }

    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {   
        if ($address->getSurcharge()) {
            $address->addTotal(array(
                    'code'=>$this->getCode(),
                    'title'=> 'Surcharge',
                    'value'=> $address->getSurcharge()
            ));
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

But using this my invoice amount is not adding this surcharge. That shows only previous amount.

Comment: Try extension instead https://magecomp.com/magento-payment-fee.html